# How to generalize a static clousure?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have the following scenario: two validation Helpers

the StringValidationHelper ...

```
public class StringValidationHelper {

    public static Validation<String> notNull = 
        SimpleValidation.from(s -> s != null, "must not be null.");

    public static Validation<String> moreThan(int size) {
        return SimpleValidation.from(
            s -> s.length() >= size, 
            String.format ("must have more than %s chars.", size));
    }
        ... // More methods (lessThan, etc)}
```

... and NumberValidationHelper.

```
public class NumberValidationHelper {

    public static Validation<Number> notNull = 
        SimpleValidation.from(n -> n != null, "must not be null");

    public static <N extends Number & Comparable<N>> Validation<N> lowerThan(N max){
        return SimpleValidation.from(
            n -> n.compareTo(max) == -1,
            String.format("must be lower than %s.", max));
    }
    ... // More methods like (greaterThan, etc)}
```

The method *from* is a static factory method that receives a Predicate and a message to eventual validation fails.

```
public class SimpleValidation<K> implements Validation<K>{
    private Predicate<K> predicate;
    private String onErrorMessage;

    private SimpleValidation(Predicate<K> predicate, String onErrorMessage) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.onErrorMessage = onErrorMessage;
    }

    public static <K> SimpleValidation<K> from(Predicate<K> predicate, String onErrorMessage){
        return new SimpleValidation<>(predicate, onErrorMessage);
    }
    ... // Omitted for simplicity
}
```

Thanks to the Validation  interface, you can enjoy a wonderfully smooth interface

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Validation<K> {

        ... // Omitted for simplicity

        default Validation<K> and(Validation<K> other) {
            return param -> {
                ValidationResult firstResult = this.test (param);
                return ! firstResult.isValid()? firstResult: other.test(param);
            };
        }
        ... // Omitted for simplicity
    }
```

So I can start, for example, a validation using the closure notNull.

Example: with NumberValidationHelper

```
public class MyValidate {
    void validate(int toValidate) {
        notNull.and(lowerThan(100)).test(toValidate).isValid();
    }
}
```

This validation framework I developed based on [this](https://medium.com/@jplanes/lambda-validations-with-java-8-86aa8143bd9f) article.

Well, notNull enclaves a type-independent behavior, so I'd like to remove the duplication of these two helpers.
I'm not finding an obvious shape without losing the fluid interface.

Because the variable is static, you can not use generics and extend the behavior, for instance.

```
public abstract class GenericHelper<K> {
    public static Validation<K> notNull = SimpleValidation.from(o -> o != null, "must not be null.");
}
```

Also it does not bother me to type Validation with Object as below:

```
public abstract class GenericHelper {

    public static Validation<Object> notNull = SimpleValidation.from(o -> o != null, "must not be null.");
}
```

... because in the call chaining, it will give compilation error since the result of notNull will be a Validation< Object > and and will be expecting a Validation< Integer >

```
notNull.and(lowerThan(100)).test(toValidate).isValid(); //Does not compile
```

Is there any way to use the Java 8 function features that keep this interface flowing generically, running away from the solutions I've tried above?

thankful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should relax the generic signature of `and`, allowing a `Validation<T>` with a more specific `T` as parameter, to produce a `Validation<T>` as result:

```
default <T extends K> Validation<T> and(Validation<T> other) {
    return param -> {
        ValidationResult firstResult = this.test(param);
        return ! firstResult.isValid()? firstResult: other.test(param);
    };
}
```

Staying with your examples, you still cannot write

```
void validate(int toValidate) {
    notNull.and(moreThan(100)).test(toValidate).isValid();
}
```

as `moreThan` returns a `Validation<String>` which can not `test` an `int`, but spotting such errors is what Generics is all about (I suppose, you have another `moreThan` method in your actual code base which you didn’t include in your question). But the following will now work with your example:

```
void validate(int toValidate) {
    notNull.and(lowerThan(100)).test(toValidate).isValid();
}
```

Sometimes, you need to test a validation of a more specific type before a more generic validation which still doesn’t work with the method shown above. One solution would be to go the same route as the JDK developers and augment [`Function.andThen(after)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) with a [`Function.compose(before)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-), allowing to swap the roles

```
default <T extends K> Validation<T> compose(Validation<T> other) {
    return param -> {
        ValidationResult firstResult = other.test(param);
        return ! firstResult.isValid()? firstResult: this.test(param);
    };
}
```

Or you create a `static` method, which allows both arguments to have a broader type than the resulting `Validation`:

```
static <T> Validation<T> and(Validation<? super T> first, Validation<? super T> second) {
    return param -> {
        ValidationResult firstResult = first.test(param);
        return ! firstResult.isValid()? firstResult: second.test(param);
    };
}
```

Note that the `static` method can be combined with the convenient instance method, so that the caller only needs to resort to the `static` method when hitting the limitations of the generic signature:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Validation<K> {
    ValidationResult test(K item);

    default <T extends K> Validation<T> and(Validation<T> other) {
        return and(this, other);
    }
    static <T> Validation<T> and(Validation<? super T> first,Validation<? super T> second){
        return param -> {
            ValidationResult firstResult = first.test(param);
            return ! firstResult.isValid()? firstResult: second.test(param);
        };
    }
}
```

So you can still write

```
notNull.and(lowerThan(100)).test(toValidate).isValid();
```

but when hitting the limitation, e.g.

```
Validation<Object> anotherCriteria;
…
lowerThan(100).and(anotherCriteria).test(toValidate).isValid();
```

does not work, you can resort to

```
Validation.and(lowerThan(100), anotherCriteria).test(toValidate).isValid();
```

Comment: super clean, nice. can I ask you about your opinion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124348/sorted-stream-derived-from-infinite-stream-fails-to-iterate ?

Comment: This code snippet had a typo and a mental lapse:
`notNull.and(moreThan(100)).test(toValidate).isValid();
`My intention was to refer to the method, which I omitted in the question, described below:
`public static <N extends Number & Comparable<N>> Validation<N>  greaterThan(N min)`
So your answer that I refer to below solves the problem intelligently.
`default <T extends K> Validation<T> and(Validation<T> other) {
    return param -> {
        ValidationResult firstResult = this.test(param);
        return ! firstResult.isValid()? firstResult: other.test(param);
    };
}`