# Sorted stream derived from Infinite Stream fails to iterate

Tags: java, java-stream

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;

class TestInfiniteStream {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        IntStream infiniteStream = new Random().ints();
        IntStream sortedStream = infiniteStream.sorted();

        sortedStream.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
    }
}
```

After compiling and executing this code I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream size exceeds max array size
```

Does sorting a stream fail on an infinite stream?

Comment: How many zeros do you expect in an infinite stream?

Comment: How does one sort an infinite amount of anything?

Comment: @NAMS infinitely slowly.

Comment: I see different behavior when the infinite stream is generated like this 

    Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream
  .iterate(0, i -> i + 1);

I would have expected to get sorted runs for some limit of elements instead of inconsistent behavior.

Comment: then you would need to use `infiniteStream.limit(someNumber).sorted();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer to “*Does sorting a stream fail on an infinite stream?*” is “*Yes.*” `sorted()` is a stateful intermediate operation which has been implemented by buffering the entire contents and sorting it, before passing any elements to the downstream operations.

In theory, it doesn’t need to be that way. Since you are using `forEach`, which has been explicitly specified as processing the elements in an undefined order, the sorting step could be omitted in your `new Random().ints().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);` use case. But even if you used `forEachOrdered`, there is a theoretically achievable correct answer. Since your stream is infinite and will repeatedly contain all `int` values, a correct sorted output would print `-2147483648` (`==Integer.MIN_VALUE`) forever, as that’s the smallest value that is contained infinite times in that stream.

However, to give this correct answer, the implementation would need specific code to handle this scenario, which is of not much practical value. Instead, the implementation handles this case like any other sorting of a stream scenario, which will fail for infinite streams.

In this specific case, the stream has an optimization that leads to a different, unusual exception message. As [Eugene pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130390/2711488), this stream behaves like a fixed size stream of `Long.MAX_VALUE` (`==2⁶³`) elements rather than a truly infinite stream. That’s fair, considering that the stream produced by `Random` will repeat after 2⁴⁸ values, so the entire stream has been repeated 32768 times before it will end instead of running forever. You are unlikely to witness this “sudden” ending after processing 9223372036854775807 elements anyway. But a consequence of this optimization is that the stream will fail-fast with the “Stream size exceeds max array size” message instead of failing with an “OutOfMemoryError” after some processing.

If you eliminate the size information, e.g. via

```
new Random().ints().filter(x -> true).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

the operation will try to buffer until failing with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. The same happens with

```
IntStream.generate(new Random()::nextInt).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

which provides no size information to the stream in the first place. In either case, it never gets to sort anything as the buffering happens before the sorting starts.

If you want to get “sorted runs for some limit of elements” as you said in a comment, you have to apply a limit before sorting, e.g.

```
new Random().ints().limit(100).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

though it will be more efficient to still use a sized stream, e.g.

```
new Random().ints(100).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I would have to scratch my head twice to understand why an infinite sorted stream would produce min values all the time, even if this would be very reasonable, in some sense. very good answer, thank you for your time

Comment: @Eugene well, after having produced `Integer.MIN_VALUE` infinite times, it would produce `Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1` infinite times, followed by `Integer.MIN_VALUE + 2` infinite times, and so on. But of course, we can’t witness the end of the first infinite chunk of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` elements. As said, producing this answer would be theoretically correct, but not necessarily “reasonable”, as giving this answer would require code explicitly written to handle this specific scenario, but why would anyone waste development resources for that…

Comment: Great answer as usual. I'm trying to wrap my head around `[..]considering that the stream produced by Random will repeat after 2⁴⁸ values`. Shouldn't it repeat after `2^32` values i.,e after returning all possible ints which is the range `[Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE]` (`2^31` negative values, 0, `2^31 - 1` positive values).

Comment: @user7 there are 2³² distinct `int` values, but that doesn’t imply that the sequence has to repeat after 2³² values. To name a simpler counter example, the decimal digits of π (pi) are made out of only ten distinct digits, but never repeat. In case of `java.util.Random`, it’s [the documented algorithm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Random.html), “*The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a linear congruential formula.*”, which determines when the generator will start repeating.

Comment: But still, the seed which is a long is downcasted to an int... So, from what `next` returns shouldn't we see a repeated int (*at least*) after 2^32?

Comment: @user7 you are confusing the value range with the uniqueness of a *sequence* of values. Does a sequence made only of the values `0…3` have to repeat after four values? Surely not, see `1`, `2`, `0`, `1`, `3`, `2`, `0`, `3`, `0`, `2`, `3`, `2`, `1`, still no repetition. That’s why I provided the example of π (pi). There are only 10¹ digits, still, the sequence made of these digits is *infinite*. You can try it with `nextBoolean`. If having only 2¹ values implied repeating after two values, you should be able to predict all results starting with the third `nextBoolean` call. Are you?

Comment: Oh. I get you now. Yes, I attributed `1, 2, 0, 1` as repetition (first duplicate). Thanks a lot for your time :). I guess after 2^48, the seed starts off again and produces the same sequence.

Comment: @user7 exactly. Note that this applies to instances of of `java.util.Random`, which is guaranteed to have the same algorithm in all implementations, but not for subclasses, like `java.security.SecureRandom` or `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom`, which (may) have different algorithms and differ between implementations.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot sort an infinite stream.

Your infinite stream `new Random().ints()` produces more integers than can be stored in an array (or any array), which is used behind the scenes for storing the integers to be sorted.  An array of course cannot hold an infinite number of integers; [only a capacity close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size).

Taking a step back, how would anyone or anything sort an infinite number of integers?  Nothing can and no one can; it would take at least an infinite amount of time.

> Does sorting a stream fail on an infinite stream?

You've kind of answered your own question; the `IllegalArgumentException` is the specific cause of the failure.  It only occurred because you made a program that attempted to do it, and you ran up against a Java array limitation.

The `sorted` method will attempt to read the entire stream before sorting anything.  It won't do any intermediate sorting before it has read the entire stream, so no sorting will be done, partial or full.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is an interesting question, unfortunately your key description is in comments. First of all, there isn't really an "infinite" stream in your case, the responsible spliterator `RandomIntsSpliterator` even says that:

> ... and also by treating "infinite" as equivalent to Long.MAX_VALUE...

And now the interesting part, that spliterator will will report these characteristics:

```
public int characteristics() {
        return (Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.SUBSIZED |
                Spliterator.NONNULL | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE);
}
```

Well, I don't know the reasons of *why*, but reporting `SIZED` or `SUBSIZED` for an infinite stream... May be it does not matter either (because you usually chain these with a `limit`).

Well because `SIZED` is reported (with a size of `Long.MAX_VALUE`), there is a sink for this internally `SizedIntSortingSink` that has a check:

```
if (size >= Nodes.MAX_ARRAY_SIZE)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(Nodes.BAD_SIZE);
```

which obviously will fail.

On the contrast `IntStream.generate` *does not* report `SIZED` - which makes sense to me, so the entire input has to be buffered by `sorted` and later handled to the terminal operation; obviously this will fail with an `OutOfMemory`.

It's also interesting to prove that `distinct` will not act as a full barrier here, waiting for all values to be processed. Instead it can pass them to the terminal operation, once it knows that this has not been seen before:

```
Random r = new Random();
IntStream.generate(() -> r.nextInt())
        .distinct()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will run for quite a while, before finally dying with a `OutOfMemory`. or as very nicely added by Holger in comments, it could hang too:

```
 IntStream.generate(() -> new Random()
          .nextInt(2))
          .distinct()
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `distinct()` still buffers the entire contents. But it doesn’t need to hold back the encountered values but can pass them directly to the consumer if not encountered before. That’s why you see values printed, but eventually, it will either, fail due to limited storage or enter an infinite loop without visible effect, once every value has been encountered. In the current implementation, it will always be the former, as 2³² `int` values do not fit into a conventional collection. But `IntStream.generate(() -> r.nextInt(1000000000)) .distinct() .forEach(System.out::println);` will hang eventually…

Comment: @Holger yes, very bad wording on my part about `distinct`. It can also be much easier with `() -> new Random().nextInt(2)`, it would still hang

Comment: Of course, the smaller the value set, the sooner it will hang without doing something useful. I just wanted to emphasize the difference between less than 2³¹ values (like my `1000000000` example) and more than 2³¹ values, as that’s the implementation specific limitation, as `distinct()` uses a backend collection which can not store more than 2³¹ values.